# Contenteditable DIV length

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

I'm trying to update a contenteditable div dynamically for which I need the length of the innerHTML of the div. When I attempt the get the length (element.innerhtml.length), I only get the length of the first line. Every check after that returns the same result.

How would I go about getting the length of a specific line or the whole div?

Thanks for the help

Comment: You should post some code for example

Answer (score 0):

I have an editable div:

`<div id='divEdit' contenteditable="true" style="height:auto;border:1px solid black;" onchange="update()"></div>`

I am trying to to get the length of the innerHTML each time I press enter:

```
<script>
            document.onkeyup = update;

            function update() {
            var editableId = document.getElementById('divEdit');
            var editableStr = editableId.toString();

            var key= event.keyCode;

            if (key== 13) { 
                alert(editableStr.length);
            }
        }
        </script>
```

Comment: This should be part of the question.